# insert one column from other tables

Tags: sql-server

i have create table which have 5 columns ie.

```
ac_no,customer_code,firstname,lastname,address
```

now i need to insert customer code from customer mast and ac_no from 2 different tables ie. deposit ac_mast and loan mast.
in above image  u see that customer code and ac_no.customer code is the persions id and ac_no is like our bank account numbers which is generated after creating customer code. i need to insert 1 columns from 1 table and other columns from other various tables.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Terrible question aside, you will need a column in each table that defines the relationship. I recommend [this book](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsql/) as a starting point to learning how SQL works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do an insert into statement with a join that selects your data.

```
INSERT INTO {tablename} (customerCode, ac_no)
  SELECT customerCode, ac_no
  FROM {deposit} inner JOIN {table1Field} AS t1 ON {table2Field} = t2
```

Replace the names in {} with your table and field names.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would you mind marking your question as answered. I'm glad this worked for you!